# How to get UIVisualEffectView to fade in animated?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view that I want to cover with a blur and have it animate in. I added the UIVisualEffectView called blurField in storyboard. This is what I hacked together, is there a cleaner way to do this? Thanks!

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.blurField.alpha = 0.0;
    [self performSelector:@selector(fillInBlur) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
}

-(void)fillInBlur {
    self.blurField.alpha = 0.1;
    [self performSelector:@selector(fillInBlur1) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.03];
}

-(void)fillInBlur1 {
    self.blurField.alpha = 0.2;
    [self performSelector:@selector(fillInBlur2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.03];
}

-(void)fillInBlur2 {
    self.blurField.alpha = 0.3;
    [self performSelector:@selector(fillInBlur3) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.03];
}

-(void)fillInBlur3 {
    self.blurField.alpha = 0.4;
    [self performSelector:@selector(fillInBlur4) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.03];
}

-(void)fillInBlur4 {
    self.blurField.alpha = 0.5;
    [self performSelector:@selector(fillInBlur5) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.03];
}

-(void)fillInBlur5 {
    self.blurField.alpha = 0.6;
    [self performSelector:@selector(fillInBlur6) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.03];
}

-(void)fillInBlur6 {
    self.blurField.alpha = 0.7;
    [self performSelector:@selector(fillInBlur7) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.03];
}

-(void)fillInBlur7 {
    self.blurField.alpha = 0.8;
    [self performSelector:@selector(fillInBlur8) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.03];
}

-(void)fillInBlur8 {
    self.blurField.alpha = 0.9;
    [self performSelector:@selector(fillInBlur9) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.03];
}

-(void)fillInBlur9 {
    self.blurField.alpha = 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 8, animation of visual effect view opacity is illegal and impossible. This is because of the special way in which it is implemented.

In iOS 9, you can just animate the blur itself, directly. Start with a UIVisualEffectView whose `effect` is `nil` and then set its `effect` to a UIBlurEffect inside an `animations:` block. The blur will animate itself into existence.

There are still some limitations, but the runtime will call them out for your clearly if you hit them. There's a good WWDC 2015 video on this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the help @matt!